# Carbon PHP Library issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have problem with PHP Library called [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com). It sometimes returning yesterdays date. I am using Arch Linux.

Here is my time settings:

```
$ timedatectl                                                                       
                      Local time: Wed 2018-02-21 17:28:24 +08
                  Universal time: Wed 2018-02-21 09:28:24 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2018-02-21 09:28:24
                       Time zone: Asia/Manila (+08, +0800)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

I compare my date with the date on this [site](https://www.timeanddate.com/). I confirm that I have the right and exact time.

The problem is when I try to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com) library, on my php code, it sometimes returning yesterdays date. I am experiencing this right now and last week.

```
dd(Carbon::now('Asia/Manila'));
```

Output:

```
Carbon @1519134564 {#793 ▼
  date: 2018-02-20 21:49:24.720553 Asia/Manila (+08:00)
}
```

Even with no specified timezone

```
dd(Carbon::now());
```

I am using Laravel Framework by the way.

EDIT=======================================

The problem is on my vagrant machine. I am using laravel homestead.

Here is the result on my homestead machine

```
$ timedatectl   
      Local time: Tue 2018-02-20 22:35:08 +08
  Universal time: Tue 2018-02-20 14:35:08 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2018-02-20 14:35:06
       Time zone: Asia/Manila (+08, +0800)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
```

Currently this is what I put on my after.sh file:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Manila /etc/localtime
echo "Asia/Manila" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

How can I set it to follow my original settings on my arch machine?

Comment: please check your timezone in config/app.php file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment here is the timezone: 'timezone' => 'Asia/Manila'

Comment: i don't know why its happening because it work perfect in my case. can you **update** your library

Comment: Ok let me update. What is your OS by the way?

Comment: my OS is ubuntu (linux).

Comment: I see. Its my vagrant box that's returning the issue. it using different date.

Comment: I already set it to on my timezone though but still its using different date